# Creating and indexing an array from a text file

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I have a text file that looks like so:

```
:SomeWord:::SomeOtherWord:::MaybeAnotherWord::
```

Assuming that I don't know how many ":" are between words or even how many words there are, but every word is after a ":", I want to take this text file in Linux terminal and set 2 local vars to the first and second word found.

I have tried to make an array from the text file and then grab the 0 and 1 indexes but it didn't work like I thought.

```
~# myarray=$(cat mytextfile.txt | tr ":" "\n")
~# for line in $myarray ; do echo "[$line]"; done
[SomeWord]
[SomeOtherWord]
[MaybeAnotherWord]
```

ok that looks like it worked but then when I try to grab by index I get unexpected results..

```
~# echo ${myarray[0]}
SomeWord SomeOtherWord MaybeAnotherWord
~# echo ${myarray[1]}

~#
```

I don't know if I'm splitting the file wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not create an array, but just a normal variable. To create an array you have to write `()` arround the `$()` again:

```
myarray=($(cat mytextfile.txt | tr ":" "\n"))
```

which can also be written as:

```
myarray=($(tr ":" "\n" < mytextfile.txt))
```

Comment: No, it creates an array of length 3. Just try it. If `$()` was quoted (`"$()"`) then you would be right.

Comment: I had not quoted it.  Not sure if `IFS` caused an issue.  I tried your commands in a new Bash session and it worked.  Edited your answer and upvoted.